# Define a new conditional column in pandas based on several string columns

Tags: pandas, string, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I am trying to define a new column in pandas if one of the other three string columns are specific values.

```
df.loc[df['member1_labels'] == 'F' or df['member2_labels'] == 'F' or df['member3_labels'] == 'F', 'total_score'] = 'F'
```

But I get the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How I can fix this?

Comment: Hey Paul, I think all you need to do is encase those conditions in parentheses, like `df.loc[(cond1) or (cond2) or (cond3), 'your_col']`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just did it, but it does not work.  The same error is showing up.

Comment: @Onur `or` is not valid for vectors, one should use `|` instead (and the parentheses!)